# Как раскрыть полностью видео миниатюру при клике

Tags: javascript, css

Ребят есть Poput окно , в котором находится 3 видео миниатюры. Как сделать чтобы при клике на них всплывал блок чуть меньше самого popup-a и воспроизводилось
 видео ? на чистом js без плагинов или css

**HTML**

```
    <!-- Ссылки на вызов модальных окон-->
<a href="#win1" class="button-image"><img src="images/banner.png"/></a>
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="win1"></a>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="content">
          <a class="close"title="Закрыть" href="#close" id="winclose"></a>
            <div id="custom_links" class="custom-links">
                <a href="#" class="custom_links app-store" title="App Store"></a>
                <a href="#" class="custom_links google-play" title="Google Play"></a>
                <a href="#" class="custom_links main-cta" title="CIBC MODERN LIFE"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="video-box-wrapper-0">
                <div class="video-trigger">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="video-box-wrapper-1" id="myImg1">
                <div class="video-trigger">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="video-box-wrapper-2" id="myImg2">
                <div class="video-trigger">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***CSS***

```
  .button-image{
    float: right;
}
/* Базовые стили слоя затемнения и модального окна  */
.overlay {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    /* фон затемнения */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    position: fixed; /* фиксированное поцизионирование */
    cursor: default; /* тип курсара */
}
/* активируем слой затемнения */
.overlay:target {
    display: block;
}
/* стили модального окна */
.popup {
    right: 0;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 1030px;
    height: 640px;
    top:0;
    /* фиксированное позиционирование, окно стабильно при прокрутке */
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid #383838;
    background: #fefefe;

    /* внешняя тень */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
}
/* активируем модальный блок */
.overlay:target+.popup {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top: 10px;
}
/* формируем кнопку закрытия */
.close {
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 13px/20px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .8s;
    transition: all ease .8s;
}
.close:before {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    content: "X";
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    font-size: 12px;
}
.close:hover {
    background-color: rgba(252, 20, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
/* изображения внутри окна */
.popup img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
/* элементы м-медиа, фреймы */
.popup embed,
.popup iframe {
    top: 15px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
}
.popup h2 { /* заголовок 2 */
    margin: 0;
    color: #008000;
    padding: 5px 0px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #adadad;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family: 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
/* параграфы */
.popup p {margin: 0; padding: 5px 0}
/*content*/
.content{
    width: 1030px;
    height: 640px;
    background: url("images/main-background.jpg") no-repeat;
}
.custom_links{
    display: block;
}
.app-store{
    background-image: url("images/app-store.png");
    position: absolute;
    width: 124px;
    height: 37px;
    left:435px;
    bottom:177px;
}
.google-play{
    background-image: url("images/google-play-fr.png");
    position: absolute;
    width: 109px;
    height: 37px;
    right: 332px;
    bottom: 177px;
}
.main-cta{
    background-image: url("images/main-cta.png");
    width: 178px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 57px;
    bottom:32px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.app-store, .google-play{
    z-index: 10;
}
.video-box-wrapper-0{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.video-trigger{
    display: block;
    transition: transform .2s ease;
 }
.video-box-wrapper-0 .video-trigger{
    width:216px;
    height:121px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    right: 57px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    display: block;
    background:url("images/prev-video-etrans_en.jpg") no-repeat;
    top:65px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.vd-box{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1999;
    display: none;
}
.video-box-wrapper-1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.video-box-wrapper-1 .video-trigger{
    width:216px;
    height:121px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    right: 57px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    display: block;
    background:url("images/prev-video-dao_en.jpg") no-repeat;
    top:203px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.video-box-wrapper-2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.video-box-wrapper-2 .video-trigger{
    width:216px;
    height:121px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    right: 57px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    display: block;
    background:url("images/prev-video-goldfish_en.jpg") no-repeat;
    top:341px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.video-trigger:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.video-trigger::after{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    top:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-image: url("images/video-play.png");
}
```

Comment: Не нужно задавать один и тот же вопрос по несколько раз

Comment: @Cheg так ответов то нету ..

Comment: в предыдущем вопросе есть ответ. но вы, видимо, поленились переделать его под свои нужды

Comment: @Cheg он не подходит под мой вопрос так как , у него просто модальное окно и воспроизводится видео , а у меня как сказать модальное окно в модальном окне и  я не знаю как это сделать